# Keep screen awake on Android Wear with covered screen

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

I'm developing a Wear OS app with Kotlin for timing during sporting activities. I'm aware of the all the battery usage ramifications but as the timer will only be used for a short period and the user will be able turn off the feature in the settings I am going ahead with this.

I've used the below which works perfectly for when the users arms go into a resting position but if the screen gets covered by a sleeve, it locks as if you cover to lock. How do i override this action?

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
}
```

I've looked at overriding gestures but that seems to only cover various wrist flicking gestures.

Comment: I haven't tried it, and suspect the watch manufacturer might disable.  Have you tried power manager wakelocks? https://github.com/google/wear-displaylock/blob/master/wear/src/main/java/net/waynepiekarski/displaylockwear/LockService.java#L100

But you should try to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, from my tests that prevents it timing out and going to sleep but not covering but you raise a valid point that it may be down to the hardware. Will keep testing based off this.